# Mailchimp? Mandrill? or both?

Tags: email, mailchimp, mandrill

I am a bit confused with Mailchimp and Mandrill, what I need to do seems to need both, let me explain:
A social network needs to send at 1am everyday a notification email to their users that have not logged in during the last 24 hours. Emails have to be personalised.
On the top of that, there are different campaigns for different list of users.
My first thought is to use the mandrill API, but I need to be able to see who unsubscribe from what campaign (a user might want to unsubscribe to one campaign but stay subscribed on another one). I cannot seem to find something that fits the bill with Mandrill... Subaccount? Tags?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure this will answer the question, but let me try:

Mandrill actually belongs to MailChimp, and was created for interfacing with it. You can use the "mandrill-api" gem - https://mandrillapp.com/api/docs/ - to interface with many of the Mandrill and MailChimp features to do the things you wanted.

A lot of times if you are attempting to do so, and run into errors such as "XXXX not found", you have to send it FROM MailChimp TO Mandrill. For instance, when you create a template in MailChimp, click the dropdown menu next to the template, and click "Send to Mandrill". You should be good from there.

Other than that, I wish you luck. While the mandrill-api gem can do everything, it has absolutely abysmal documentation. There are multiple third-party gems that provide similar functions (mandrill-rails is a popular one) that you might have better luck with, but I have not used them myself.

Answer (score 0):

Notifications = Mandrill = 1:1 emails
Campaigns = MailChimp = 1:many emails

Typically, notifications are 1:1 emails - your system sends a single user an email as a result of some trigger within the system. The trigger might match multiple users at the same time, but emails are sent to them each individually - probably via a loop in your code. Mandrill supports templates to personalise these emails if required.

Campaigns are sent to mailing list members in bulk, where the same (personalised) email is sent to multiple users at the same time. This is either triggered by hand (you manually create and send a campaign) or is based on a scheduled trigger (eg autoresponders or scheduled campaign mailing).

Notifications are generally system-related emails and while you do have the technical ability to let users unsubscribe from them in Mandrill, typically I would consider that a configuration option you'd give them in their personal control panel on your site.

Campaigns are something you MUST allow users to unsubscribe from to comply with anti-spam laws, so will contain unsubscribe links in the footer of every email.